# Voting on articles behaves differently from Q&A when you're not signed in

Tags: bug, voting

On article pages, e.g. [this (unpopular) one](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68475140/faster-cloud-storage-transfers-using-the-gcloud-command-line), even though I wasn't signed in, I clicked the vote buttons.  Instead of showing a dialog inviting me to join Stack Overflow like I'd see on a question/answer,

[image: Join Stack Overflow dialog on questions/answers]

it shows a minor notification telling me that I haven't enough rep, but that my vote has been recorded, like it did when I didn't have enough reputation, but I was signed in and I voted on questions/answers:

[image]

(It's also red, whereas the one for questions, when I hadn't enough rep, was blue if I remember correctly.)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320779/are-votes-by-anonymous-users-recorded

Comment: It is blue now, but used to be red: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259591/282094 perhaps the new code uses the old message.